# Create Instance of a C# Generic Class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, generics

> The title is possibly worded incorrectly, so please show me the correct terms.

I've got a base class called **DAL_Base** that accepts a generic type `T`. The type `T` comes from our many classes in our Business Objects layer, and each one of them has a corresponding Data Access Layer.

**DAL_Base** accepts parameters that allows me to specify the Stored Procedure names and parameters that I use to call methods to select, insert, and update records.

What I currently seem to be stuck on is that I can't seem to find a way to instantiate a new instance of my **DAL_Base**, which needs to initialize the various variables.

Partial listing:

```
public class DAL_Base<T> where T : IDisposable, new() {

  public DAL_Base<T>() { // <= ERROR HERE
    // initialize items that will be used in all derived classes
  }

}
```

The error VS2010 is giving me is:

> Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

I have tried creating constructors without parenthesis, but that is not useful either.

When I search, all I seem to be able to return are ways to create instances of my generic type `T`. That was easy to find out how to do!

MSDN's [An Introduction to C# Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) did not seem to cover this, either.

Comment: A somewhat better title (since you ask for one) would be: _Writing an instance constructor of a generic class or struct_ The same syntax is used for a `static` constructor of course, if you need one. **Constructors** are the method-like members that run when people write a `new` object expression.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not have angle brackets (`<` and `>`) on the constructor.

```
public class DAL_Base<T> where T : IDisposable, new()
{
    public DAL_Base()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You should not have the generic type argument in your constructor:

```
public class DAL_Base<T> where T : IDisposable, new() {

  public DAL_Base() { // <= this should work
    // initialize items that will be used in all derived classes
  }

}
```

Since you have decorated the class itself with the type argument, the type is available in the constructor:

```
  public DAL_Base() {
     var listOfObjects = new List<T>();
  }
```

Comment: That is exactly the sort of thing I am looking to do, too!

Answer (score 4):

`public DAL_Base() { // <= NO ERROR HERE :)`

The class is generic, the constructor is not. You tried to add an additional generic parameter to the constructor, which it cannot have.